# Беспрерывно выполнять код N минут подряд

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

Как в python беспрерывно выполнять команду

```
print("Hello world")
```

в течении 10 минут? Имеется ввиду беспрерывное выполнение команды, а не ее запуск раз в секунду.

Comment: `while True:` и внутри цикла поставить проверку текущего времени

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Можно с помощью модуля `time`

```
import time

start = time.time()

while time.time() - start < 600:
    print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь `timedelta` для расчета времени выполнения:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

duration = 10
future = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=duration)

while future > datetime.now():
    print("Hello world")
```